# Pages with an SVG "jump" in Code Editor so I can't edit the code

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm trying to edit a page using code editor and have found a really strange bug/issue. Perhaps unique to me, I don't know. Wordpress 5.7. Theme = GeneratePress.

I am editing (or trying to anyway) a page using the code editor. For some reason, in code editor, the cursor "jumps" to the bottom of the page, and keeps jumping back there multiple times a second. So I can't edit anything that's not the bottom line.

Testing this a little, I noticed I can edit the code pages that don't have an SVG, but any with an SVG have this strange behaviour.

I wish I could film the code, so you can see it move. In the SVG part of the code, every second, the following code appears, then disappears. This code occurs after

```
<svg and before xmlns="http....": aria-hidden ="true" height="1em" width = "1em"
```

Anyone else seen this behaviour and know what causes it? Also how to resolve it?

To repeat, pages without an SVG behave as normal - i.e. I can edit the code. It's only pages with an SVG that display this odd behaviour.

Comment: Questions: Are you adding the `<svg>` yourself ? When you talk about the editor, what are you referring to (Gutenberg, WYSIWYG, Default admin code editor ... ) ? Can you add the paste ALL related code differences between a working page and a non-working page

Comment: Using the block editor (GenerateBlocks?) It has the setting Visual Editor or Code Editor. It's Code Editor which has the problems when there's an SVG used on the page. The page still works, I just can't edit it using the Code Editor. I'm not sure how the SVGs were uploaded, they're a button icon with Icon SVG HTML in the Icon section of the button. They have been there for 6 months without an issue, until now. Happy to share the SVG HTML, but it's long.

Comment: As it's not related to Wordpress core, you should open an issue with your theme/plugins editor.

Comment: I'll give that a shot, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a known issue with GenerateBlocks.

Comment: A release of GenerateBlocks yesterday, 18/3, solved this